# XPATH: Get element from html code

Tags: xml, xpath

I have an HTML code:

```
    <div class="g-col3 m-colspan2"><script data-name="HH/Cart/SpecialOffer" data-params="
                {
                    &quot;id&quot;: &quot;7-day-ru-without-discount&quot;,
                    &quot;trl&quot;: {

            &quot;recount&quot;: &quot;Пересчитать&quot;,
            &quot;addtocart&quot;: &quot;В корзину&quot;,
            &quot;alreadyInCart&quot;: &quot;В корзине&quot;

                    }
                    ,
            &quot;regionId&quot;: 1828
                }
            "></script><div class="price-spoffers__gift-title">Вакансия Стандарт+ бесплатно</div><div class="price-spoffers__gift-desc">при покупке доступа к базе резюме</div><div class="price-spoffers__action-title">быстрый старт:
                </div><div class="price-spoffers__special-offer-title">Неделя доступа к резюме в регионе: Брянская область</div><span class="price-spoffers__actual-price">2000 руб.</span><div class="price-spoffers__special-offer-plus">
                    +Вакансия Стандарт+ бесплатно</div><form method="post" action="/employer/invoice/purchase">

I need this
**<div class="price-spoffers__button"><button class="HH-Price-SpecialOffer-AddToCartButton" type="button" autocomplete="off">В корзину</button></div>**
peace of code

<input type="hidden" name="_xsrf" value="ea931c153e61866f8b6af65684b0d4e4"/></form></div>
```

I separate peace of code I need extract with using xpath. But how can I check first for g-col3 m-colspan2 exist and if yes then go inside and extract price-spoffers__button?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways really. One possible way is by matching class attribute of the `<div>` :

```
//div[@class='g-col3 m-colspan2']/div[@class='price-spoffers__button']
```

or by matching text content of the `<button>` :

```
//div[@class='g-col3 m-colspan2']/div[button='В корзину']
```

Comment: But how can I cheak first for g-col3 m-colspan2 exist and if yes then go inside and extract price-spoffers__button???

Comment: @java_user updated to include check of `div[@class='g-col3 m-colspan2']`

Comment: //div[contains(@class, 'm-colspan2')]//button[contains(@class, 'HH-Price-SpecialOffer-AddToCartButton')] - Thank you I found out it